# Suppose that B is a finitely generated A-algebra. If B is a noetherian ring, is A noetherian?

Tags: commutative-algebra

I know how to prove that A noetherian implies B noetherian using Hilbert's basis theorem. However, I wasn't able to produce an answer to the converse which probably is false.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $k$ be a field, and let $R=k[x,y]$.

Let $M$ be the set of monomials $m \in R\;$such that  $\deg(m,x) < \deg(m,y)$.

Define subrings $A,B$ of $R$ by
$$A = k[M]$$
$$B = A[x]$$
Then $B\;$is finitely generated over $A$.

Also, $B=R$, so $B\;$is noetherian.

But $A\;$is not noetherian, since the ideal of $A\;$generated by $M$ is not finitely generated.

Comment: Thank you. I was thinking of something along the lines $A=K[x,xy,xy^2,...]$ and $B=A[y]$. Would it be correct?

Comment: Yes, that would work. It's similar, in spirit, to the example I gave.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ be any non-Noetherian ring, let $\mathfrak{m}$ be a maximal ideal of $A$, and set $B := A/\mathfrak{m}$. Then $B$ is a finitely generated $A$-algebra and it is Noetherian since it is a field.